# How do you release a software update without breaking previous version?

Tags: iphone, ios, unit-testing, version-control

We have been building apps for quite a while now and they have turned out well. We are now commissioned to build a large-scale multiplayer game for iOS that is similar to Clash of Clans.

My question is:

Before we start coding, how do we prepare ourselves to be able to release subsequent versions of the game?

Assuming the game has millions of players (or even thousands), we cannot afford to release an update that breaks the previous version.

What are the best practices in handling these type of software releases? We want every version to be thoroughly tested, without having to go back and test every previous feature.

Comment: What do you mean "break the previous version?"  If you have version 1, and version 2, how would applying the update break version 1 for people?  If you updated, you would be at version 2, not 1, so it wouldn't break version 1 for that person, since they would be at version 2. Do you want version 1 and version 2 to coexist at hte same time on the same servers/network code?

Comment: I guess @Spentak is talking about a public API consumed by the game as a webservice or so.. In this case all you need is to never change a method signature, instead add new methods and overload existing ones.

Comment: Clash of Clans forces app (client) updates (they don't support multiple versions simultaneously). Also, consider unit tests.

Comment: I am more so talking about this scenario: We introduce brand new feature D - but what we didn't know was that feature D, broke features A,B,C from version 1. We are aware of unit testing - but is that the only safeguard we have? Is it enough? Perhaps we need a dev environment where we post new local and server updates before updating the live version?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It all depends on what you are using for your game. As previously mentioned there are scenarios where players are forced to update to continue playing the game, similar to online Xbox/PS3 titles or MMORPGs.

Project-wise, you can implement some of the following practices:

- Adopt a test-driven development approach. This will ensure that, in future updates of your app, nothing is broken or regressed.
- Determine whether or not you will force players to update the app in order to keep playing.
- Implement a good QA pipeline where every major (or even minor) change is thoroughly tested before you deploy anything to the live application.

These are some of the most common and simple ways to ensure you deliver a solid product without breaking existing functionality.